# do we need to define modules in Angular 2, in ES6 every js file is treated as a module?

Tags: angular, systemjs

is it necessary to define Angular 2 modules for every component I write ? in ES6 every js file is treated as a module.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one `NgModule` or as many as you want. But you need at least one `NgModule`. These Angular2 modules are unrelated to other module systems.